# endian-independent base64_encode/decode function

Tags: c, endianness

I was googling around for these two C functions that I happen to need, and the cleanest I came across was http://fm4dd.com/programming/base64/base64_stringencode_c.htm But it looks to me like the following little part of it...

```
void decodeblock(unsigned char in[], char *clrstr) {
  unsigned char out[4];
  out[0] = in[0] << 2 | in[1] >> 4;
  out[1] = in[1] << 4 | in[2] >> 2;
  out[2] = in[2] << 6 | in[3] >> 0;
  out[3] = '\0';
  strncat(clrstr, out, sizeof(out));
}
```

...is going to be endian-dependent (ditto a corresponding encodeblack() that you can see at the above url). But it's otherwise nice and clean, unlike some of the others: one had three of its own header files, another called its own special malloc()-like function, etc. Anybody know of a nice, small, clean (no headers, no dependencies, etc) version, like this one, that's more architecture-independent?

**Edit** reason I'm looking for this is that base64_encode() will be done in a php script that's part of an html page, passing that encoded string to an executed cgi program on a far-away box. And that cgi then has to base64_decode() it. So architecture-independence is just an added safety, just in case the cgi's running on a non-intel big-endian box (intel's little).

**Edit** as per comment below, here's the complete code along with a few changes I made...

```
/* downloaded from...
   http://fm4dd.com/programming/base64/base64_stringencode_c.htm */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * file:        base64_stringencode.c v1.0                                  *
 * purpose:     tests encoding/decoding strings with base64                 *
 * author:      02/23/2009 Frank4DD                                         *
 *                                                                          *
 * source:      http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c for encoding            *
 *              http://en.literateprograms.org/Base64_(C) for decoding      *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ---- Base64 Encoding/Decoding Table --- */
char b64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

/* decodeblock - decode 4 '6-bit' characters into 3 8-bit binary bytes */
void decodeblock(unsigned char in[], char *clrstr) {
  unsigned char out[4];
  out[0] = in[0] << 2 | in[1] >> 4;
  out[1] = in[1] << 4 | in[2] >> 2;
  out[2] = in[2] << 6 | in[3] >> 0;
  out[3] = '\0';
  strncat(clrstr, out, sizeof(out));
  } /* --- end-of-function decodeblock() --- */

char *base64_decode(char *b64src /*, char *clrdst */) {
  static char clrdstbuff[8192];
         char *clrdst = clrdstbuff;
  int c, phase, i;
  unsigned char in[4];
  char *p;

  clrdst[0] = '\0';
  phase = 0; i=0;
  while(b64src[i]) {
    c = (int) b64src[i];
    if(c == '=') {
      decodeblock(in, clrdst); 
      break; }
    p = strchr(b64, c);
    if(p) {
      in[phase] = p - b64;
      phase = (phase + 1) % 4;
      if(phase == 0) {
        decodeblock(in, clrdst);
        in[0]=in[1]=in[2]=in[3]=0; }
      } /* --- end-of-if(p) --- */
    i++;
    } /* --- end-of-while(b64src[i]) --- */
  return ( clrdstbuff );
  } /* --- end-of-function base64_decode() --- */

/* encodeblock - encode 3 8-bit binary bytes as 4 '6-bit' characters */
void encodeblock( unsigned char in[], char b64str[], int len ) {
  unsigned char out[5];
  out[0] = b64[ in[0] >> 2 ];
  out[1] = b64[ ((in[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((in[1] & 0xf0) >> 4) ];
  out[2] = (unsigned char) (len > 1 ? b64[ ((in[1] & 0x0f) << 2) |
           ((in[2] & 0xc0) >> 6) ] : '=');
  out[3] = (unsigned char) (len > 2 ? b64[ in[2] & 0x3f ] : '=');
  out[4] = '\0';
  strncat(b64str, out, sizeof(out));
  } /* --- end-of-function encodeblock() --- */

/* encode - base64 encode a stream, adding padding if needed */
char *base64_encode(char *clrstr /*, char *b64dst */) {
  static char b64dstbuff[8192];
         char *b64dst = b64dstbuff;
  unsigned char in[3];
  int i, len = 0;
  int j = 0;

  b64dst[0] = '\0';
  while(clrstr[j]) {
    len = 0;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
      in[i] = (unsigned char) clrstr[j];
      if(clrstr[j]) {
        len++; j++;   }
      else in[i] = 0;
      } /* --- end-of-for(i) --- */
    if( len ) {
      encodeblock( in, b64dst, len );  }
    } /* --- end-of-while(clrstr[j]) --- */
  return ( b64dstbuff );
  } /* --- end-of-function base64_encode() --- */

#ifdef TESTBASE64
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  char *mysrc  = (argc>1? argv[1] : "My bonnie is over the ocean      ");
  char *mysrc2 = (argc>2? argv[2] : "My bonnie is over the sea        ");
  char myb64[2048]="", myb642[2048]="";
  char mydst[2048]="", mydst2[2048]="";
  char *base64_enclode(), *base64_decode();
  int  testnum = 1;
  if ( strncmp(mysrc,"test",4) == 0 )
    testnum = atoi(mysrc+4);

  if ( testnum == 1 ) {
    strcpy(myb64,base64_encode(mysrc));
    printf("The string [%s]\n\tencodes into base64 as: [%s]\n",mysrc,myb64);
    strcpy(myb642,base64_encode(mysrc2));
    printf("The string [%s]\n\tencodes into base64 as: [%s]\n",mysrc2,myb642);
    printf("...\n");
    strcpy(mydst,base64_decode(myb64));
    printf("The string [%s]\n\tdecodes from base64 as: [%s]\n",myb64,mydst);
    strcpy(mydst2,base64_decode(myb642));
    printf("The string [%s]\n\tdecodes from base64 as: [%s]\n",myb642,mydst2);
    } /* --- end-of-if(testnum==1) --- */

  if ( testnum == 2 ) {
    strcpy(mydst,base64_decode(mysrc2)); /* input is b64 */
    printf("The string [%s]\n\tdecodes from base64 as: [%s]\n",mysrc2,mydst);
    } /* --- end-of-if(testnum==2) --- */

  if ( testnum == 3 ) {
    int itest, ntests = (argc>2?atoi(argv[2]):999);
    int ichar, nchars = (argc>3?atoi(argv[3]):128);
    unsigned int seed = (argc>4?atoi(argv[4]):987654321);
    char blanks[999] = "                           ";
    srand(seed);
    for ( itest=1; itest<=ntests; itest++ ) {
      for ( ichar=0; ichar<nchars; ichar++ ) mydst[ichar] = 1+(rand()%255);
      mydst[nchars] = '\000';
      if ( strlen(blanks) > 0 ) strcat(mydst,blanks);
      strcpy(myb64,base64_encode(mydst));
      strcpy(mydst2,base64_decode(myb64));
      if ( strcmp(mydst,mydst2) != 0 )
        printf("Test#%d:\n\t in=%s\n\tout=%s\n",itest,mydst,mydst2);
      } /* --- end-of-for(itest) --- */
    } /* --- end-of-if(testnum==3) --- */

  return 0;
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
#endif
```

Comment: But the endianness *is* important. You could add in a htonl/s in the encoding and ntohl/s in the decoding before doing anything else. Then you know you always have the same endianness.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your endianess-dependency doubts? Maybe give an example where you get wrong/different results for calculations in both endianesses?

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm not getting different results -- see edit above (but wait a minute until I put it there)

Comment: In my experience, you get endianess troubles when looking at bits (compilers have different opinions on where the LSBit is in a bitfield) or when mixing sizes of datatypes (compilers have different opinions of where the LSByte is in a struct). Arrays are harmless, as long as you do not switch between sizes the order is guaranteed. Shifting bits within several bytes (without getting a bitfield into the picture) seems also harmless.

Comment: @JesperBangsholt Yeah, that sounds simple enough.  I already messed with it a little for my own purposes, which is what made me notice and wonder about it in the first place. This little more messing is certainly worth the trouble. Post as an answer if you'd like a "check". Thanks.

Comment: @Yunnosch Okay, yeah, you may be right that it's not any potential problem, and that I'm overthinking it (or mis-thinking it). unsigned char whatever[999] doesn't have any endianness whatsoever, only if you say int n; unsigned char *nptr=(unsigned char *)(&n); Then nptr[i] might have different values on different boxes.

Comment: That `strncat` males me deeply suspicious. It assumes the decoded string has no embedded NULs. That might commonly be true, but since base-64 is 8-bit clean, nothing stops the encoded string from containing encoded NULs.  Second, using `strncat` instead of `strcat` is pointless: it's clear that out is NUL-terminated, much less clear that `clrstr` has enough room. And `stfncat` won't help you avoid that potential buffer overflow. Finally, using `str[n]cat` is silly. It makes a linear algorithm quadratic.

Comment: In short, I  understand the desire to avoid overengineered solutions, but this particular "simple" solution might not be appropriate either.

Comment: Thanks @rici , I hadn't even noticed that potential "gotcha". I'd have thought there'd be some generally-accepted gnu code for this, but there doesn't seem to be. Oh, wait -- yes there does, so I think I'll probably just use that https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/base64-invocation.html -- and put a function wrapper around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not endian-dependent. Base64 in itself is 4 bytes to 3 bytes encoding, and doesn't care about the actual representation in memory. However, if you expect to transfer little/big endian data, you must normalize the endianness *before* encoding and after decoding.

That fragment just addresses all bytes independently. It would be endian-dependent if it loaded 4 bytes in `uint32_t` or so and using some bit twiddling produced an output that would be copied into the result buffer as is.

---

However that code is dangerously broken with its `strncat` and wouldn't work with embedded NUL bytes. Instead you should use something like

```
void decodeblock(unsigned char in[], unsigned char **clrstr) {
     *((*clrstr) ++) = in[0] << 2 | in[1] >> 4;
     *((*clrstr) ++) = in[1] << 4 | in[2] >> 2;
     *((*clrstr) ++) = in[2] << 6 | in[3] >> 0;
}
```

which would work with embedded NULs.

Comment: What's about the last line of the OPs question: 'out[3] = '\0';'?

Comment: @AndreKampling it is not needed for anything. It is an ill-aided attempt at making the buffer suitable for strncat, but strncat with limit 3 wouldn't ever scan `out[3]` or the 4th character in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, Antti. That may be the best approach. But he's doing a strncat() because, rightly or wrongly (probably wrongly), he **always** passes a ptr to the **beginning** of the clear string (see the link to his code), so your're always replacing the first few bytes rather than adding on to the end. Instead,  you'd need to first bump the target ptr by strlen(*clrstr), and finally add another terminating '\000' to keep the clear string always null-terminated. But you're right, the whole thing's a little messy (but some of the other stuff I saw was even messier). (P.S. strncat limit is actually 4)

Comment: By the way, I'm not entirely sure null bytes are even a possible problem. The input in[] bytes are segments of a base64-encoded string. And the "standard" defined bytes comprising base64 "digits" are never nulls. In fact, they're all >16, so even the >>4 in[] bytes can't get zero'ed out. But, when all's said and done, I think you guys were right that endianness wasn't ever a problem in the first place.

Comment: No, first of all, the `in[]` is *already* bytes in the range 0..63, they're not base64-digits. Second, we're talking about the output - this is a block decode function and the output is 3 binary bytes in range 0...255 and using strncat there is very much wrong. If the decoded 3 byte block is `255, 0, 255`, the use of `strncat` would cause `255, 0, 0` be written ot the output instead. This is a gross mistake.

Comment: **OH!!!**, look at that, right you are! 0<=in[i]<=63. Hard to miss where he does that p-b64, but I guess I must be pretty talented at missing things. I'm going to have to take a closer look. I've edited my question to include his original code with a few changes, including changes to his unit test. It now has several tests, including a loop where it submits long random strings. I tested it with 9,999,999 different random strings, each 777-bytes. And every single encoded string subsequently decoded to exactly the original one. So I'm thinking it somehow works, though it looks like it shouldn't.

Comment: I agree it doesn't matter the endianess of the data input. However, the encoding itself does have an endianess which does matter for encoders/decoders to be compatible. The encoding shown is big-endian. The 6-MSbs of the first byte go into the first character, however, a little-endian encoding would put the 6-LSbs of the first byte into the first character. Endianess does very much matter.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of endianess and having code compatible on platforms of differing endianess...

Firstly, there is the endianess of the processing platform hardware, the endianess of the data being transmitted and the endianess of the base64 encoding/decoding process.

The endianess of the base64 coding determines whether, to form the first character, we take the lower 6-bits of the first byte, or the upper 6-bits of the first byte. It appears base64 uses the latter which is big-endian format.

You will need your encoder/decoder to match regardless of the platform, so the code you show with the fixed bit-shifting is already going to work on either big or little endian platforms. You don't want your little endian platform to use little-endian bit shifting by placing the lower 6-bits of the first byte into the first encoded character. If it did, it would not be compatible with other platforms, so in this case you don't want platform dependent code.

However, when it comes to the data, you may need to convert the endianess, but do this with the binary data, not as part of the base64 coding or the encoded text.